# analyze all of the public methods in linkedListDS class, giving the O or θ complexity of each one,

Tags: java, performance, big-o

So here is the first method. what is the complexity of these methods ? I am not sure how to determine it and why it is same thing with the find method

```
public E peekFirst(){
    //just return value of first item, don't need to remove
    ;
}

public E find(E obj){
    if(this.isEmpty())
        return null;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Would this be Big OH?". Are you trying to find the complexity of the method, or are you totally lost even with the definitions?

Comment: Im trying to find the complexity of the method

Comment: Well, I can't do all your homework for you. Show some effort first.

Answer (score 1):

peekFirst is `O(1)` since it always takes a constant time to be executed.

find is `O(N)`, since in the worst case, the element you are looking for is at the end of the list, and you will have to loop through all the `N` elements in the list to get to it